# Is this possible to send response back to page by doing some if/else in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I want to know that is this possible to send response back by using some if/else on response we get from server under success in $.ajax..

ajax

```
$.ajax({

    url  : "request/register.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : 'firstName='+firstName + '&lastName='+lastName + '&userName='+userName + '&email='+email + '&password='+password + '&con_password='+con_password,
    dataType : "text",
    beforeSend : function(http){
       $('#reg').val("Submitting....");
    },
    success : function(response,status,http){
        var text = response;
        alert(text);
        if(text != "<span class=\"error\" data-icon ='&#xea0f;'>Empty Fields</span>"){
               alert("Done");             
        }else{
               alert("oOps")
        } 

    },
    error : function(http,status,error){
        alert('server error');
    }

})
```

registeration.php

```
//creating a variable for error messages
 $error = "";
//creating a variable for success messages
 $success = "";
 //form validation
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){


    $firstName    =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstName'    ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $lastName     =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastName'     ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $userName     =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userName'     ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $email        =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'        ,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
    $password     =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'     ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $confirm_pass =  trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'con_password' ,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));


   //checking for empty feilds
    if($firstName == "" || $lastName == "" || $userName == "" || $email == "" || $password == "" || $confirm_pass == ""){
        $error = "Empty Fields";
    }

    //checking username length 

    if(empty($error) && strlen($userName)<=5){
      $error = "Username must be greater than 5 characters";
    }

    //checking for username existence

     if(empty($error) && user_exist($userName)){
        $error = "Username already exist";
     }

    //email validation
     if(empty($error) && !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      print_r($_POST);
      $error = "Invalid Email address";
    }

    //checking for email existence

     if(empty($error) && email_exist($email)){
        $error = "Email already exist";
     }

    //checking password length
     if(empty($error) && strlen($password)<=8){
      $error = "Password must be greater than 8 characters";
    }

    //matching confirm password
   if(empty($error) && $password !== $confirm_pass){
      $error = "Password not match";
    }

    if(empty($error)){
      if(user_registration($firstName,$lastName,$userName,$email,md5($password))){
        $success = "Registered Suceessfully";
      }else{
        $error = "Something went wrong";
      }
    }

 }

  if(!empty($error)){
      echo "<span class=\"error\" data-icon ='&#xea0f;'>".$error."</span>";
    }

  if (empty($error) && !empty($success)) {
     echo "<span class=\"success\" data-icon ='&#xea10;'>".$success."</span>";
   }
```

If response is something like  than i want to set input[type="text"] values should be same what user type and input[type="password"] should be blank & in other case if response is something like  i want all the input feilds empty..

Comment: Please show your all source code.

Comment: try `json_encode($your_post_data)` on your success;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But as the body *may* change overtime, it's best to do your `if`/`else` logic on the [HTTP/1.1 Status Codes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

For example;

In your error response, simply return an error code `400 Bad Request` by using [`http_response_code()`](http://php.net/http_response_code)

```
http_response_code(400);
```

And in your success response, simply return a `201 Created`

```
http_response_code(201);
```

Now, in your jQuery, you can just look at the return status code and do the appropriate thing for the end-user

```
//[...]
success : function(response,status,http) {
    if(http.status === 201) {
       alert("User created");
    } else {
       //Assume there was an error
       //Do some error logging for the end-user
       alert("Could not create the user");
    }
}
```